# Why roots have radial vascular bundles while stems have conjoint?

Tags: plant-anatomy

Why not the whole plant has the same arrangement of vascular bundle,  why there is a difference of arrangement in roots and stems (radial in root and conjoint in stem) ,  what is the purpose of this difference?